# Are the repository credentials defined in gradle stored somewhere in the generated APK?

Tags: android, gradle, reverse-engineering

Suppose we have the following repository definition in gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 's3://my-top-secret-repo/releases'
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey 'MY_TOP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
            secretKey 'MY_TOP_SECRET_SECRET_KEY'
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, is there some way to someone reverse engineer the generated android APK and discover `MY_TOP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `MY_TOP_SECRET_SECRET_KEY`?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle build configurations are not stored in an apk. The build tool (in this case Gradle) uses this configuration to fetch the dependencies and build the apk including the `.class` files from those dependencies.

But you should pay attention when you store passwords in Java/Kotlin files as strings. These can be reversed engineered for sure.